# Dynamic banner for use on external sites

Tags: plugin-development, functions, media, customization

Pro question:

we would like to display our most current wordpress articles on external sites (something like advertisments or banners).

I think this could be easily done with iFrames, but I doubt that other people are willing to integrate them. **Is there a way to dynamically create an image (png, jpg, whatever), which lists the recent articles?**

Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi Andre, please read [ask] and file an [edit] showing what you tried, where you are stuck, etc. This is a prerequisite for asking questions.

Comment: Yes. There is nearly always a way to do it, but this question is pretty broad and the solution is arguably mostly a PHP question. I'd suggest you first research [dynamic image creation](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+dynamic+image) in PHP. Once you get the hang of that rolling it into a WordPress context shouldn't be too difficult.